# Is it possible to apply for a Ph.D. position as an international student without all recommendation letters in Europe, Australia, and New Zealand?

Tags: phd, recommendation-letter, europe, australia, new-zealand

I have been working with my supervisor for years. Now, when I submit applications to universities abroad, most of them require two professor recommendation letters. When I informed my former supervisor, with whom I have worked on several articles, he initially agreed to send them but later I found out he hadn't. I remind him several times not to forget, but he still doesn't send them. In Iran, we live under a dictatorship, and the Iranian government is trying to control emigration and puts pressure on university professors not to send recommendation letters. Professors' emails are on the servers of domestic universities and are regularly monitored, and perhaps these professors are afraid to do such a thing via university email. Is there a way to solve this problem, and is it necessary for both professors I introduced as referees to send recommendation letters? What should I do now?

Comment: Europe is large and diverse. There are European countries where recommendation letters were traditionally not a part of the application process. To be honest, having or lacking a recommendation from an Iranian professor would not matter at all if you applied to one of my PhD positions. What would matter much more is that you would need to convince me that you are actually interested in the specific PhD position and not just any position that gets you out of your country.